# How to exit a while loop depending of the result of an Axios call?

Tags: vue.js, while-loop, axios

In order to make sure a user-entered word exists, I need to keep prompting (`while` loop) for a word until the word API finds the word.

My question is: how can I exit the `while` loop depending of Axios call result?

Below is my code so far.

```
const wordApiBaseUrl = 'https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v1/references/sd4/xml'
while (true) {
  const wordToGuess = prompt('Enter a word:').toLowerCase()
  const endPointUrl = `${wordApiBaseUrl}/${wordToGuess}?key=${wordApiKey}`
  this.axios.get(endPointUrl).then(res => {
    if (res.data.includes('def')) {
      break
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const wordApiBaseUrl = 'https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v1/references/sd4/xml'

const vm = this; // <--- assuming this is the Vue instance
const dispatcher = {

    execute: function() {
        const wordToGuess = prompt('Enter a word:').toLowerCase()
        const endPointUrl = `${wordApiBaseUrl}/${wordToGuess}?key=${wordApiKey}`
        const dispatcher = this;
        vm.axios.get(endPointUrl).then(res => {

            if (!res.data.includes('def')) {
                dispatcher.execute();
            }
        })
    }
}
dispatcher.execute();
```

Rather than using a `while` loop or using an `async/await` you can use recursion in our promise. If the result is not satisfied, re-run the AJAX call.

Comment: Thanks, getting some `_this.execute is not a function` error though. It's a `Vue` app and I need to call Axios with `this.axios`

Comment: Apologies, I used an anonymous function `this` doesn't exist in anonymous JS lambdas. Try it now

Comment: Also, you could capture this outside of the `dispatcher.execute`, I'll update my answer to show you how. EDIT: Updated to use `this.axios` by aliasing `this` outside of `dispatcher.execute`

Comment: Thank you, still getting the same error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this.execute is not a function` though. I don't understand why

Comment: Hm.. I've updated the answer and captured the `dispatcher` outside of the AJAX call. Try that. Running this locally (without using `vm.axios`) gives me the expected results.

Comment: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: dispatcher.execute is not a function at eval` :/

Comment: When you log `dispatcher.execute` what does it say? What about logging `dispatcher`?

Comment: For `dispatcher.execute` is says `undefined`, for `dispatcher` I'm getting the `VueComponent` object

Comment: That's definitely strange... So `vm === dispatcher` when you run this?

Comment: I had forgot to stop using an arrow function and instead use a normal one like in your new version, works fine now. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, yeah that'll do it. Glad to help!